# getting providers of a llvm instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Analyzing llvm IR file ( .bc or .ll ) for every instruction it is possible, using the provided functions, to determine the list of instructions that consume it result. What about the other way around – are there llvm functions that allow for every instruction ( or better – for every operand of an instruction ) to determine the list of instructions that provide it with the necessary resources.
Being able to know the users of the result of an instruction it is possible to calculate such a data. The question is if it is already calculated and, if yes, how to obtain it.

Comment: Yes, that is possible, see getOperand() and related.

Comment: Thank you. Now is it possible to get the closer of consumers/providers of a llvm instruction - are there llvm functions that allow, for every instruction, to determine the list of all instructions that affect it execution ( not necessarily directly ) and list of all instructions that are affected by it execution ( again, not necessarily directly ).
Knowing the consumers/providers of an instruction make it possible to calculate such a data. The question is if it is already calculated and, if yes, how to obtain it.

Comment: LLVM can't possibly know, at best you can over-approximate. `getOperand()` gets all SSA dependencies, we call this the "use-def" graph ("def" being short for "SSA definition"). LLVM has an analysis pass named MemorySSA to attempt to determine whether a `load` instruction (or other memory-reading instructions) depend on other memory-writing instructions. If you see a call to an external function that may read a file from disk, LLVM can't know which other function may have written to that same file previously.

Comment: What I am trying to determine is resource dependencies ( and not memory aliasing ).
For example if (1) %1 = 1 && (2) %2 = %1 && (3) %3 = %2 the function that I am looking for shall tell that closer of providers of instruction (3) consists of instruction (1) and instruction (2). Being able to determine providers of an instruction allows for implementation of such a function, but before doing that I would like to find out if this is provided by LLVM's API.

Comment: The existing instructions already are the nodes of the graph you are asking for. You can look "upward" on the graph via `operands()` +all, and "downward" on the graph via `user()` +all. We don't rebuild the entire transitive closure of all of them per instruction, that would be too slow for a production compiler, just to replicate data that is already efficiently accessible. Many passes walk this graph doing an action one node at a time.

Be aware that the graph may have cycles. `%x = add i32 %x, %x` is valid when inside a block that is not reachable. PHI nodes use operands over backedges.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance! I am sorry that the functions I need are not part of the LLVM’s API. At the same time I am surprised that this is the case. LLVM is known for extensive optimizations it supports ( or allows to implement ). While implementing my optimizer-autoparallelizer ( see www.dalsoft.com ) I learned that having the closure of providers/consumers AS A SET, although is expensive to create/maintain, offers immense advantages during code processing. For example it allows for efficient set operations – intersection, subtractions etc. which prooved to be helpful.